# After upgrading to Xcode 11, apps doesn't show some UILabels

Tags: xcode, uilabel, ios13, xcode11

After upgrading to Xcode 11, some of my apps stopped showing texts. I can see images, buttons, etc but almost no texts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Dark Mode is the answer. Dark Mode is enabled by default. If you want to disable it, add the following to you Info.plist:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>light</string>
```

Beware, though: as mentioned [here](https://zonneveld.dev/how-to-support-dark-mode-in-ios-apps/), "Currently, Dark Mode support is not required by Apple for an app submit, but this can be required soon.". And also "If your app doesn’t support dark mode, users may dislike your app, which can result in a bad rating.".

Cheers!

Comment: Why disable dark mode? Why not fix the color of your labels?

Comment: @rmaddy because someone, like me, might have lots of apps, with some deprecated code and, might need to make a quick release to fix bugs regarding iOS 13. Besides, Apple says that your app might not need to use dark mode.